# How to map multiple values to a single value in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to map multiple values to a single value and return that single value when I will search? For example:

```
Fruit -> Mango, Banana, Apple
Vehicle -> Car, Bus, Truck
Place -> Berlin, NewYork
```

Let's say, I will give input "**Truck**" and it will search and return back "**Vehicle**".

How can I find my desired mapping functionality in Python 3? So far, I can see there are some way using dictionary or tuple. But, how to achieve that and what is the best way to implement this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary should work just fine.

```
mapping = {
    "Fruit": ["Mango", "Banana", "Apple"],
    "Vehicle": ["Car", "Bus", "Truck"],
    etc.
}

thing = "Apple"

for category, examples in mapping.items():
    if thing in examples:
        return category
```

Or as @user2357112 suggested:

```
mapping = {
    "Mango": "Fruit",
    "Apple": "Fruit",
    "Truck": "Vehicle",
    "Bus": "Vehicle",
    etc.
}

thing = "Apple"

if thing in mapping:
    return mapping[thing]
```

Actually I think I like this better, because you don't need a loop.

Comment: Seems like it'd make more sense to have the mapping the other way around. `"Mango": "Fruit", "Banana": "Fruit"`...

Comment: `return` makes no sense in this context. You might as well just break, and capture the data after the loop based on the value of the vars when the loop stopped. Because that's what you are going to have to do after that return.

Comment: @OysterShucker I was using return as shorthand for "you found the target value, now go handle it however you want to."  That might be an actual return, or a print, or an email, or whatever.

Comment: @JohnGordon - I knew that, actually. However, considering the very low entry point on this question, that could end up being confusing for some. I have decades of experience, you likely also have decades of experience, the OP and others that would need this information might not even have 10 days of experience. Also, I do not agree that the second method is better. It only works if you bloat your dict. With 3 things it may be no big deal. What if there are 3 million things?

Comment: @OysterShucker I don't think it's reasonable to expect that an answer will spell out every possible implementation detail.  Questioner asked how to find a mapping, and I answered that.  We ought to have some expectation that readers can adapt answers to their specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'fruits', 'vehicle' and 'place' as keys and the list of each items as values in a `dict`:

```
dct = {
       'Fruit' : ['Mango', 'Banana', 'Apple'],
       'Vehicle' :['Car', 'Bus', 'Truck'],
       'Place' : ['Berlin', 'NewYork']
       }

for k, v in dct.items():
    if "Truck" in v:
        print(k)
        break

#Output: Vehicle
```